# Объединение нескольких таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблицы:

1. Билеты (предназначена для выдачи талона к врачу в больнице) она состоит из таких полей:

   1. IdTicket
   2. DoctorKod (код доктора из таблицы Врачей)
   3. RegistrationKod (код регистрации из таблицы Регистрации)
   4. DateReception (дата приема)
2. Регистрации (предназначена для регистрации пациента в больнице) она состоит из таких полей:

   1. IdRegistration
   2. DateRegistration
   3. ParticientKod (код пациента из таблицы Пациенты)
3. Пациенты:

   1. IdParticient
   2. FIO
   3. Address
   4. CityKod

Как можно получить данные из таблицы *Билеты*, но чтобы было выведено *FIO* пациента из таблица *Пациенты*, т.е. нужно вывести в билете имя пациента, который записался на прием к врачу.

Я пытался сделать через `inner join`, но не очень. Вообще есть идея просто добавить в таблицу *Регистрации* код пациента, но если есть возможность обойти это, было бы круто.

Ниже я прикрепил *sql*, в котором я все это делаю, но вывожу вместо *фио* пациента дату его регистрации (из таблицы Регистрации).

```
SELECT Doctors.IdDoctor, Doctors.FIO, Registrations.IdRegistration, 
  Registrations.DateRegistration, Tickets.DateReception
FROM (
  (
    Tickets INNER JOIN Doctors
    ON Tickets.DoctorKod = Doctors.IdDoctor
  )
  inner join Registrations
  on Tickets.RegistrationKod = Registrations.IdRegistration
)
```

Answer (score 1):

надо просто связать все необходимые таблицы по ключевым столбцам.

примерно так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34ced/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table bilety (id int, doktor int, registracija int);
create table registracii (id int, pacient int);
create table pacienty (id int, fio text);
create table doktora (id int, fio text);

insert into bilety values (1, 1, 1);
insert into registracii values (1, 1);
insert into pacienty values (1, 'пациентов п.п.');
insert into doktora values (1, 'докторов д.д.');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select doktora.id as doktor, doktora.fio as doktor_fio,
  registracii.id as registracija, pacienty.fio as pacient_fio
from bilety, registracii, pacienty, doktora
where bilety.doktor = doktora.id and bilety.registracija = registracii.id
  and registracii.pacient = pacienty.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34ced/1/0)**:

```
| id |           fio | id |            fio |
|----|---------------|----|----------------|
|  1 | докторов д.д. |  1 | пациентов п.п. |
```

Comment: Кириллица: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3888/1

Comment: @msi, спасибо, буду знать, но я ошибся — вопрос был про mysql, а не ms/sql. я уже внёс коррективы в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят, я просто подправил

```
SELECT Doctors.IdDoctor, Doctors.FIO, Registrations.IdRegistration,
  Registrations.DateRegistration, Particients.FIO,
  Tickets.DateReception
FROM (
  (
    Tickets INNER JOIN Doctors
    ON Tickets.DoctorKod = Doctors.IdDoctor
  )
  inner join Registrations
  on Tickets.RegistrationKod = Registrations.IdRegistration
) 
inner join Particients
on Registrations.ParticientKod = Particients.IdParticient
```